# How to delay starting a function in React or NextJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to redirect as soon as I access a page of my app in NexJS.

I would like when this component is rendered, after 5 seconds it is redirected to home.

I tried with this code:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
   
      redirect('/home')
    }, 2000);

  return () => clearTimeout(timer);
  }, []);
```

this is my component:

```
'use client'
import React,{useEffect} from 'react'
import Image from 'next/image'
import { redirect } from 'next/navigation'

const Success = () => {

  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
   
      redirect('/home')
    }, 2000);

  return () => clearTimeout(timer);
  }, []);


  return (
    <div className="container_success">
      <div className="content_success">
        <Image
          src={'/images/close.svg'}
          alt="close"
          width={26}
          height={26}
          className=""
        />
        <div className="success_text">
          <h1 >
            Operation success !
          </h1>
          <p >
            Thank you.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <span className="spinner_container">
        <Image
          src={'/images/spinner.svg'}
          alt="success-spinner"
          width={26}
          height={26}
          className="animate-spin"
        />
        <p className="">
          Beign redirected...
        </p>
    
      </span>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Success
```

but it doesn't work.  Where am I wrong?

Comment: This code should work as intended. Can you share full code?

Comment: Yes, sure. I did it

Answer (score 1):

## `useRouter` for Client Components and `redirect` for Server Components

[According to the documentation, `redirect` is a server-side function.](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/redirect) It is listed under the *Server Components* section in the documentation. Therefore, you should use [the `push` method in `useRouter`](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/routing/linking-and-navigating#userouter-hook) in your client-side components instead of `redirect`.

Your code should look like this:

```
// ...
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation'

const Success = () => {
  const router = useRouter()

  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      router.push('/home')
    }, 2000)

    return () => clearTimeout(timer)
  }, [])

  // ...
```

Comment: It should be noted that on versions of Next.js before Next.js 13, you would have to add `router.isReady` to the `useEffect` dependencies. It is no longer required in Next.js 13 though.